# Golang TCP Client does not receive data from server, hangs/blocks on conn.Read()

Tags: go, tcp, network-programming

I'm taking a dive into the networking side of Go, and I'd thought I'd start with a TCP Client and Server.

I am able to get the client to connect to the server and send a simple message ("Hello") successfully. However, I can not get the server to send back a response (or the get the client to read the response).

Here is the code.

**Server**

```
Address := "localhost:9999"
Addr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", Address)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", Addr)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer listener.Close()

//server loop
for {
    conn, err := listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        continue
    }

    go handle(conn)
}

func handle(c net.Conn) {

    totalBytes, message := connRead(c)
    fmt.Println(c.RemoteAddr())

    fmt.Println(string(message[:totalBytes]))

    c.Write([]byte("Hi"))
    fmt.Println("Replied")
    c.Close()
}

func connRead(c net.Conn) (int, []byte) {
    buffer := make([]byte, 4096)
    totalBytes := 0

    for {
        n, err := c.Read(buffer)
        totalBytes += n
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                log.Printf("Read error: %s", err)
            }
            break
        }

    }
    return totalBytes, buffer
}
```

**Client**

```
    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "localhost:9999")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    _, err = conn.Write([]byte("Hello"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    tBytes, resp := connRead(conn)
    fmt.Println(tBytes)
    fmt.Println(string(resp[:tBytes]))

func connRead(c net.Conn) (int, []byte) {
    buffer := make([]byte, 4096)
    totalBytes := 0

    for {
        fmt.Println("Stuck?")
        n, err := c.Read(buffer)
        fmt.Println("Stuck.")
        totalBytes += n
        fmt.Println(totalBytes)
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                log.Printf("Read error: %s", err)
            }
            break
        }

    }
    return totalBytes, buffer
}
```

From what I can tell it's not a problem with the server. When I run the client, everything stops right after `fmt.Println("Stuck?")`. This leads me to belive that it's messing up in the `n, err := c.Read(buffer)` statement somehow. The server doesn't even print out the messeage length (5) and message ("Hello") untill after I Ctrl-C the client. If I comment out the read and printings in the client, then things run smoothly.

I've tried googling for answers, but nothing has come up.

What am I doing wrong? Am I using conn.Read() wrong in the client?

**EDIT:**

I actually do have access to Linux, so here are the SIGQUIT dumps for the pertinent functions.

*Server*

http://pastebin.com/itevngCq

*Client*

http://pastebin.com/XLiKqkvs

Comment: At a quick glance, it looks like client and server block reading to EOF on the connection.  Send SIQUIT to the running applications to find out where they blocked.

Comment: I'm on Win 7, which doesn't support SIGQUIT.

Comment: Both programs are blocked on read. One or both of the peers should [close the write side](https://godoc.org/net#TCPConn.CloseWrite) of the connection to unblock the other peer.  Alternatively, you can add message framing and stop reading after reading a complete message.

Comment: How do you know the server is receiving something if it doesn't print the msg length? Is it connRead or conn.Read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for {
    n, err := c.Read(buffer)
    totalBytes += n
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            log.Printf("Read error: %s", err)
        }
        break
    }

}
```

It is because you are reading from connection till EOF error occurs

```
conn.Write([]byte("Hello"))
```

The above statement won't reach EOF at all until you actually closes the connection

On pressing ctrl+c client side the connection will be closed, So EOF occurs at server side, That is the reason why it is exiting server side for loop and printing these

```
127.0.0.1:****
Hello
Replied
```

If you want to make this work you should not read the connection till EOF

There are many other alternatives for this

1. Chose a delimiter and read at the server until the delimiter occurs and respond back after that. Check out this [link](https://systembash.com/a-simple-go-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/)
2. Send number of bytes to read from client side before sending the actual message, First read number of bytes to read from the server side and then read those many bytes from the connection

Comment: Thank you. I decided to go with alternative number 1.

However, now when I try to send another message from the same client after I receive a response from the server, the server doesn't seem to get the second message.

Comment: @JimDoe Can you share the source what you had written, So that i can help you out

Comment: Of course!

Client:
http://pastebin.com/k3B0zuVr

Server: 
http://pastebin.com/9AXXjVwx

The second message sends. But I get zero bytes back from the server.

Comment: On the server side in for loop handle connection you are calling `listener.Accept()` for every request, so you need to call `net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)` every time you send request from client

Comment: @Tej why does `conn.Write([]byte("Hello"))` never reach EOF?